# Import multi module project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, scada

I am trying to get started with Eclipse SCADA and import the projects from their git [repository](http://git.eclipse.org/c/eclipsescada/).

I have cloned the following projects:

```
org.eclipse.scada.external
org.eclipse.scada.utils
org.eclipse.scada.base
org.eclipse.scada.protocols
org.eclipse.scada.core
org.eclipse.scada.releng
```

For each project I did mvn verify in the parent folder and imported the projects in Eclipse. I also changed target platform. However, I still seem to have problems with their dependencies.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Eclipse SCADA java projects are not developed with "Maven first". So you should disregard maven completely while in the IDE. The maven build is basically only used to build the project unattended.

The issue with the target platform is more complex. We were a bit sloppy in providing a always working target platform (and it is actually difficult to keep them up to date, since the versions of the bundles are fix).

I made a target platform file for the current version, you can find it here: https://gist.github.com/CptMauli/ec6eda37734f0108510f

To make it work properly please download a classic eclipse put it somewhere and create an environment variable ECLIPSE_432_HOME which points to it. Alternatively you can just change the first entry  in the target file and point it directly to it.

The reason behind it is, if you would use your own eclipse installation, it is possible that bundles installed there conflict with bundles provided in the target platform or from your workspace. This is actually mostly not even a problem when compiling, but as soon as you start a client or a server, Eclipse will complain about duplicated bundles.

If you have any more questions please go to our mailing list: https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/scada-dev
or our google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openscada
or write to me directly at juergen dot rose at ibh-systems dot com